# How to add icon of tab to layout?

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to mimic standard approval page and to be even more similar to origin I want to add icon of approving object. What element I need to add or what attribute to put?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a visualforce `<apex:SectionHeader>` element that displays default header with icon.
Alternatively you can use some css magic, find the icons you're interested in with your browser's inspector tool (make sure to look after inside the css, not the `src` attribute, see the picture below) and use it as you like. Good luck!

[image: img source]